# SQL Server: FULL Backup Job Error (Operating system error 32)

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have approx 12 databases(including system databases) in support of our product. We have a job that takes FULL backup of each database weekly once(Sunday), differential each day and transactional every 4 hours.

One of my client is getting following error in job history, during FULL backup job execution.

Message:

> Executed as user: domain\user. Cannot open backup device 'bakup_device_name(\absolute path\msdb.bak)'. Operating system error 32(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). [SQLSTATE 42000](Error 3201) BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000](Error 3013). The step failed.

Please help me the different approaches to find the root cause of the issue and solution for the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MS SQL error 15105 is an error message which occur when a user try to
>   create database file backup to a network shared disk or when hosting
>   database file on a network share is not supported, and as a result
>   such error message event take place.

The possible reasons and hoe to fix it here: [WHAT IS MS SQL ERROR 15105 ?](http://en.mssqldatabaserepair.org/what-is-ms-sql-error-15105)

Comment: Thanks @sepupic , that helped in solving the issue